# SQL query efficiency between two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I had the following query (MySQL) that is very slow (about 15 seconds). I have changed the names of columns and tables, so sorry if it has any type error; the original query is working, keep only the concept, no the literal query.

```
SELECT 
id,
b, 
(SELECT MAX( day )
FROM all_days
WHERE all_days.id = X.id
) AS day
FROM X
```

Note that all_days has more than 2 million rows. I have 3 indexes: One for the id, other for the day and other for {id,day}

But if I separate the query in N queries with UNION, it only takes about 1 second or less with the same result:

```
<?php
$ids = getIds(); // get all ID from X with a query
$i = 0
foreach ($ids as $id) {
     if ($i++ > 0) {
         $query .= " UNION ";
     }
     $query .= "SELECT MAX( day )
     FROM all_days
     WHERE all_days.id = $id";

}
?>
```

Any ideas of how could I increase the speed without doing UNIONS?

EDIT (added structure):

```
Table X:
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
b  INTEGER -- extra info

Table all_days:
day_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
id INTEGER FK X.id
day DATETIME

all_days indexes:
id
day
id,day
```

Comment: It isn't clear from your question - is there an index on `all_days.id` ?

Comment: Please post your table definitions and the indexes used to complete the information

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have added the strucutre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a try with this query:

```
SELECT 
id,
b, 
max_day
FROM X
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT id, MAX(`day`) AS max_day
  FROM all_days
  GROUP BY id
) AS max_days
ON max_days.id = X.id
```

The reason why this should be much faster is, that here per id the max(day) is stored in memory (or temporary table on disk if too large) and is then connected to table X. In your query you read every row of table X and for every row you query table all_days.

Comment: @user3796513 Did you try it?

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I have to learn why this INNER JOIN is so efficient (0.0006 sec) vs the original subquery.

Comment: @user3796513 The reason is simply, that here per id the max(day) is stored in memory or temporary table on disk if too large and is then connected to table X. In your query you read every row of table X and for every row you query table all_days. Extremely slow as you experienced. Your approach with `union` doesn't make sense at all, I must say ;)

Answer (score 0):

In a simple situation like this (assuming the combination of X.id / X.b is unique) then this can be done without the need for a sub query:-

```
SELECT X.id,
        X.b, 
        MAX( all_days.day ) AS day
FROM X
LEFT OUTER JOIN all_days
ON all_days.id = X.id
GROUP BY X.id, X.b
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Your version is working too, but it takes about 3 seconds while @fancyPants 's one took less than 0.001 seconds. I don't know why there is so much difference.

Comment: Normally for a simple query like this it would be quicker as it can use indexes for the join. MySQL is poor at joining to a sub query (not a real issue when there are only a few records from the sub query) which could impact @fancyPants solution. With the covering index on the all_days table covering both id and day (in that order) the should join efficiently. Using an INNER JOIN would help, but this wouldn't cope if X has records not matched on all_days (fancyPants solution has this issue anyway). Could you run this query as an EXPLAIN on your tables and post the results please.